# When should I use ruamel_yaml vs. ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have been able to find a few snippets written about `ruamel_yaml` vs. `ruamel.yaml`, but not a clear concise explanation of the difference.  Could someone please explain very briefly?

`ruamel_yaml` is found here:
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/ruamel_yaml

Comment: @Anthon is my browser broken, or did someone delete you answer?

Comment: Ok, this is really weird.  There was an answer and some comments, and now they're gone.

Answer (score 0):

*Original answer by @Anthon was somehow deleted and can be found here http://5.9.10.113/64592897/when-should-i-use-ruamel-yaml-vs-ruamel-yaml :*

*Reposting it on his behalf:*

---

There is no package ruamel_yaml on PyPI, so I suspect those snippets refer to a port of the package ruamel.yaml to a non pip based installer.

There are various "clones" of ruamel.yaml out there that were created because:

people having problems with Python not being the most used programming language (Javascript)
installers not supporting all the features of pip used by the ruamel.yaml installer. E.g. namespace packaging (IIRc conda has this problem)
people not able to use a different revision control system but Subversion or Git
If you can, I recommend always using ruamel.yaml and installing from PyPI (disclaimer: I [@Anthon] am the author of that package). That way you will have the latest bugfixes, and best support if problems occur (e.g. when trying to adapt a snippet using ruamel_yaml)